# Python run bash command which saves data to file

Tags: python, bash

I'm trying to run a bash-command in python where the bash-command saves data to a file rather than displaying it. An example of such command is

```
$ echo 'foo' > bar.txt
```

currently my code looks like the following

```
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.communicate()
```

As I run the python-code no `bar.txt` is generated. Any idea on how to save the data from the bash-script? The data should not be displayed only saved.

Comment: Redirection using `>` and shell-builtins like `echo`, require `bash`.  So add `shell=True` to your `Popen`.

Comment: There is no point passing a `stdout` argument if you redirect the commands output with `>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `print()`. Simple as that. Anything that would normally be printed to the console will instead be printed to a file, because of the `>` command.

```
~$ python3.5 your_script.py > bar.txt
```

If you do not want to run your python script with `>`, then you will need to use python’s file operations to write a string version of your data to a file:

```
with open('bar.txt', 'w') as F: 
    F.write(data)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that option is not available as other prints need to be displayed for user-action

Comment: Then you need to assign the output as a string in python, and use `with open(filename, 'w') as F: F.write(string)` to write to a file.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `subprocess.Popen()` does not run the command via the shell, and therefore I/O redirection operators have no special meaning -- they are treated as ordinary arguments.  The easiest way to achieve what you're after is to make it use the shell.  With `Popen()`, you would pass `shell=True`, and you would *not* split the command string:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(bashCommand, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

You should also consider whether the `subprocess.call()` (Python 2) or `subprocess.run()` (Python 3) convenience functions offer any advantage to you.  It's not clear whether they do, however; in particular, you would need to use the same `shell` argument in both those cases as well.